# Froyo apps2sd, can a widget go app2sd

Tags: android, widget, usb, android-2.2-froyo

Froyo apps2sd, can a widget go app2sd, once usb is mounted widget gets uninstalled, you unmount the usb it never enables again, tried enabling it programatically, no luck, can any body help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If your app has widgets, you may not support app2sd, or else they simply won't show up in Froyo (they won't even appear in the list of available widgets).

If you have a huge application, consider adding widgets as a separately downloadable application. Mark the main application app2sd and the widgets one "internal only".

EDIT: This is incidentally described in detail here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html:

**Applications That Should NOT Install on External Storage**

[...]

App Widgets

Your App Widget will be removed from the home screen. When external storage is remounted, your App Widget will not be available for the user to select until the system resets the home application (usually not until a system reboot).